# How to set up python testing in Databricks

Tags: python, testing, pyspark, databricks

I am new to Databricks and I have created a data profiling notebook within it. I now want to unit test some functions, but I feel a bit lost. I've done a lot of searching for best ways to do this, and I cannot find great answers. My code is not meant to be a sophisticated development project, it is more of a means to an end that I will be using for a few months, but I still want to make sure I have some test coverage.

The laziest approach would be to add tests within the same notebook. But what I would rather do is create a testing notebook to test functions in my profiling notebook, but I cannot figure out if this is a good practice in Databricks or not. I'm looking for guidance on how to set up testing for this type of project.